# window.on("load") function in HTML content is not executing in Tinymce

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, tinymce-5

I have a HTML which contains a window.on("load") function. and placing that html in Tinymce 5. But its not rendering window.on("load") function. Following is my code

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <h1>Some content</h1>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(window).on("load",function() {
                alert(1)
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
<script>
      const load = () => {
        console.log("load event detected!");
      }
      window.onload = load;
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Yuvraj. But still its not working. looks like Tinymce is not allowing any script to be executed which is added as a content in it.

Answer (score 0):

Please check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70339873/javascript-functions-in-content-of-of-tinymce/70367301#70367301). Probably you have faced the same problem. TinyMCE does not allow `<script>` elements by default due to security concerns (such as XSS attacks). But if you are sure you need them, the [`extended_valid_elements`](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/content-filtering/#usingextended_valid_elementstoallowscriptelements) config option should help.